# node.js : how to see HTML body of email using imap-simple and mailparser

Tags: node.js, imap

I'm trying to retrieve the HTML content of an email.
i'm using **imap-simple** and **mailparser**.

`emails` parameter have an actual mail and i'm able to explore it's parts.

The problem is that mailparser is not calling the events 'data' or 'headers'

My question is how to use mailparser (or simpleparser) with imap-simple in order to see HTML content of email's body.

This is what i run:

```
const imap = require('imap-simple');
imap.connect(emailData).then(function (connection) {
    return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
        let searchCriteria = [
            'UNSEEN'
        ];

        let fetchOptions = {
            // TEXT - includes body of email
            // HEADER - includes subject and other headers
            bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT'],
            markSeen: false
        };

        return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(function (emails) {
                mailparser.on("data", function (mail_object) {
                    console.log(mail_object.textAsHtml);
                });

                mailparser.on("headers", function (mail_object) {
                });
                // send the email source to the parser
                mailparser.write(emails[0]);
                mailparser.end();
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thx

Comment: `emails` is not an array of actual e-mails, it's an array of [`ImapMessage`](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap#data-types) instances.

Comment: how can i extract the actual email from ImapMessage so it will fit mailparser?

Comment: I have no idea, but why do you need to parse it at all? From what I understand, it's already split up into distinct parts (like headers, body, attachments, etc).

Comment: It is split up into distinct parts. but what i'm trying to do is to see the HTML of the body. and i didn't find out how to do so with the parts. any ideas?

Comment: There's an example in the README that finds all the attachments. You can probably modify that to find the HTML parts: https://github.com/chadxz/imap-simple#download-all-attachments-from-all-unread-email-since-yesterday